# sql give list of numbers in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I was looking at this example. This makes it look like single quotes are not required in the where clause when you give a list of numbers. I am using an oracle database if that makes a difference.

https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-in/

```
SELECT
    product_name,
    list_price
FROM
    production.products
WHERE
    list_price IN (89.99, 109.99, 159.99)
ORDER BY
    list_price;
```

So why is toad complaining when I do this? It says invalid identifier as the error message.

This is the query that fails.

```
select * from table1 where id in (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Toad does not complain when I do this.

```
select * from table1 where id in ('1', '2', '3', '4');
```

Comment: Which of the three queries you showed fails? Which datatypes do you use for your columns?

Comment: Not related to the question but, do not read SQL Server tutorial and apply them on Oracle . Oracle differ a lot from SQL Server. Moreover take a look on [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and update the question with a practical example

Comment: Your ID field must not be of type number.

Comment: What field type is `production.products.list_price`? That would inform you of whether you send it a number or a string-literal.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Added the message `This is the query that fails.`.

Comment: Could you please add the create table command of that table?

Comment: @JonasMetzler I didn't create the table. How would I check the datatype?

Comment: @alexherm how would I check the datatype?

Comment: You've written you are using Toad. I don't use it, but it should be able to show the create table command or at least the datatypes of the columns. In Oracle SQL developer, you can just enter a table name and then press shift and f4 to show all details about this table.

Comment: In Toad you can put your cursor on the table name and press F4 to Describe Object.

Comment: @alexherm thank you. It has a char datatype for some reason.

Comment: 'Invalid identifier' suggests a problem with naming, not values. Are you sure you didn't use double quotes, like `in ("1", "2", "3")`? That would tell SQL to treat them as identifiers, which would then fail as the table has no column named "1", "2" or "3".

Comment: The rule isn't *"single quotes are not required in the where clause when you give a list of numbers"*. It's about how you [specify literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Literals.html) and whether they are compatible with the values you are comparing them to.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson It is a char datatype for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you are using your expected datatype. In my case I was using `CHAR(12)` thats why I needed quotes.

```
SELECT 
    COLUMN_NAME,
    DATA_TYPE,
    DATA_LENGTH,
    DATA_PRECISION,
    DATA_SCALE
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
Where TABLE_NAME = 'table1';
```

If that doesn't work your table may be in capital letters so try this.

```
SELECT 
    COLUMN_NAME,
    DATA_TYPE,
    DATA_LENGTH,
    DATA_PRECISION,
    DATA_SCALE
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
Where TABLE_NAME = upper('table1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was about fetching different numbers, let's have a look on an easy way to do this.

Of course, if the column always holds numbers only and strings should not be allowed, we should just change its datatype.

And of course, if we just want to check for a few numbers like 1,2 and 3, we can use an `IN` clause like shown in the question.

But let's assume we can't change the datatype because also strings can occur and we need to accept a big range of numbers.

For example, we want to accept all numbers between 200 and 300. We dislike to write an `IN` clause with 101 values, don't we?

So we can use `VALIDATE_CONVERSION` to make sure we consider numeric entries only.

Then we use `CAST AS INT` to check the number should be between 200 and 300.

The query will be this one:

```
SELECT id
FROM table1
WHERE VALIDATE_CONVERSION(id AS NUMBER) = 1
AND CAST (id AS INT) BETWEEN 200 AND 300
ORDER BY id; -- sorting is of course not needed. Remove it if not intended.
```

We can try this out here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7QE6Xld7)

Comment: What is the `= 1` for? I am not familiar with using `VALIDATE_CONVERSION`.

Comment: I means it can be converted, 0 it can not. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD